# How should I specify Asian char, and String, constants in Java?

Tags: java, character

I need to tokenize Japanese sentences. What is best practices for representing the *char* values of kana and kanji? This is what I might normally do:

```
String s = "a";
String token = sentence.split(s)[0];
```

But, the following is not good in my opinion:

```
String s = String.valueOf('あ'); // a Japanese kana character  
String token = sentence.split(s)[0];
```

because people who read my source might not be able to read, or display, Japanese characters. I'd prefer to not insult anyone by writing the actual character. I'd want a "romaji", or something, representation. This is an example of the really stupid "solution" I am using:

```
char YaSmall_hira_char  = (char) 12419; // [ゃ] <--- small
char Ya_hira_char       = (char) 12420; // [や]
char Toshi_kj_char      = (char) 24180; // [年]
char Kiku_kj_char       = (char) 32862; // [聞]
```

That looks absolutely ridiculous. And, it's not sustainable because there are over 2,000 Japanese characters...

My IDE, and *java.io.InputStreamReaders*, are all set to UTF-8, and my code it working fine. But the specter of character encoding bugs are hanging over my head because I just don't understand how to represent Asian characters as *chars*.

I need to clean-up this garbage I wrote, but I don't know which direction to go. Please help.

Comment: *"I'd prefer to not insult anyone by writing the actual character."* - What?  No westerner would consider Kana an insult.

Comment: I would comment such literals so that someone who reads it with a font without those characters knows what's supposed to be there, but I see no reason not to just use the first option.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I wouldn't appreciate any Cyrillic or Hangul written in source code. I'd be very annoyed if I was forced to learn even an ounce of Cyrillic, Hangul, etc. I want to code in Java, and that's it. I absolutely don't care about those other writing systems.

Comment: If you just want to transliterate Japanese into Romaji, you can look into [JUnidecode](http://www.ippatsuman.com/projects/junidecode/index.html).

Comment: @kinyo Kanji literals *are* Java. The keywords and most class names are in English, but the language is quite specific about the acceptability of arbitrary Unicode. It may be a good idea to use Latin characters for linker symbols, but if you're dealing with Japanese text, use Japanese characters for your constants.

Comment: @chrylis I'm not sure I understand. A regex I might want is "^.*?でいる。" But now, I'm doing ("^.*?" + Const_DE + Const_I + Const_RU + DOUBLE_WIDTH_PERIOD) just so people who can't read kana can read my source code. But, really the only way is to write the "^.*?でいる。" regex and not worry if some people can't read it. Don't you agree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> because people who read my source might not be able to read, or display, Japanese characters.

Then how could the do anything useful with your code when dealing with such characters is an intergral part of it?

Just make sure your development environment is set up correctly to support these characters in source code and that you have procedures in place to ensure everyone who works with the code will get the same correct setup. At the very least document it in your project description.

Then there is nothing wrong with using those characters directly in your source.

Comment: I agree with this answer. If your program specifically deals with the Japanese language, then it's not going to make sense to anyone that doesn't have some basic knowledge of the language, and trying to accommodate 非識字者 is just going to make the code more confusing for those that could have actually read it.

Comment: I don't want to drag you into  written Japanese, but... there is no way to represent kanji using English chars. So, there's no way to systemically express a kanji as constants. Which means, the kanji just have to be "hard-wired" into regex expressions, right? I guess I have to say "if you cannot read my regex, let me give you an "Intro to Written Japanese" book to study." I mean, no one is going to read my code anyway so it does not really matter. Your 164-k posts convinced me. thanks.

Comment: @kinyo: my written Japanese is rusty but servicable :) Actually there is a systematic way to give latin-character names to kanji - the Unicode standard gives each character such a name. But using separate constants is just terribly verbose and won't *really* help someone without understanding of Japanese either. However, Hardcoding them into regexes or other strings should not be a big problem - people just have to recognize them as characters. They probably just won't understand your tokenizing logic, and there is a danger of them not recognizing encoding problems.

Comment: @kinyo: or are you talking about the `char` type in Java? That's actually an interesting aspect: I believe that all kanji commonly used in Japanese are part of the Basic Multilingual Plane and thus can be represented as a single Java `char` - but sometimes texts may include exotic kanji that may require a surrogate of chars and thus the `char` type is not fully appropriate to represent a single character in your code.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Thank you for catching this bug. Actually, it is possible that I might encounter exotic kanjis ("hyogaiji kanji"). I'll have to do some testing and re-design to account for this. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that what you are currently doing is unsustainable.  It is horribly verbose, and probably a waste of your time anyway.

You need to ask yourself who exactly you *expect* to read your code:

- A native Japanese speaker / writer can read the Kana.  They don't need the romanji, and would probably consider them to be an impediment to readability.
- A non Japanese speaker would not be able to discern the meaning of the characters whether they are written as Kana or as romanji.  Your effort would be wasted for them.
- The only people who *might* be helped by romanji would be non-native Japanese speakers who haven't learned to read / write Kana (yet).  And I imagine they could easily find a desktop tool / app for mapping Kana to romanji.

So lets step back to your example which you think is "not good".

```
String s = String.valueOf('あ'); // a Japanese kana character  
String token = sentence.split(s)[0];
```

Even to someone (like me) who can't read (or speak) Japanese, the surface meaning of that code is clear.  You are splitting the String using a Japanese character as the separator.

Now, I don't understand the significance of that character.  But I wouldn't if it was a constant with a romanji name either.  Besides, the chances are that I don't *need to know* in order to understand what the application is doing.  (If I do need to know, I'm probably the wrong person to be reading the code.  Decent Japanese language skills are mandatory for your application domain!!)

The issue you raised about not being able to the display the Japanese characters is easy to solve.  The programmer simply needs to upgrade his software that *can* display Kana.  Any decent Java IDE will be able to cope ... if properly configured.  Besides, if this is a real concern, the proper solution (for the programmer!) is to use Java's Unicode escape sequence mechanism to represent the characters; e.g.

```
String s = String.valueOf('\uxxxx');  // (replace xxxx with hex unicode value)
```

The Java JDK includes tools that can rewrite Java source code to add or remove Unicode escaping.  All the programmer needs to do is to "escape" the code before trying to read it.

---

Aside: You wrote this:

> *"I'd prefer to not insult anyone by writing the actual character."*

What?  No Westerner would or should consider Kana an insult!  They may not be able to read it, but that's not an insult / insulting.  (And if they do feel genuinely insulted, then frankly that's *their problem* ... not yours.)

The only thing that matters here is whether non-Japanese-reading people can fully understand your code ... and whether that's a problem you *ought to be* trying to solve.  Worrying about solving unsolvable problems is not a fruitful activity.

Comment: "Insult" was a poor choice of words. My thinking had mistakenly been that my writing of the actual Japanese characters placed a burden on the reader to think about written Japanese.

Comment: @kinyo - OK.  But I don't think there's much you can do about that.  If people need to know what the Kana mean to understand your code, then using romanji doesn't really help, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Michael has the right answer, I think. (Posting this as an Answer rather than a Comment because Comment sizes are limited; apologies to those who are picky about the distinction.)

If anyone is working with your code, it will be because they need to alter how Japanese sentences are tokenized. They had BETTER be able to deal with Japanese characters at least to some degree, or they'll be unable to test any changes they make.

As you've pointed out, the alternatives are certainly no more readable. Maybe less so; even without knowing Japanese I can read your code and know that you are using the 'あ' character as your delimiter, so if I see that character in an input string I know what the output will be. I have no idea what the character means, but for this simple bit of code analysis I don't need to.

If you want to make it a bit easier for those of us who don't know the full alphabet, then when referring to single characters you *could* give us the Unicode value in a comment. But any Unicode-capable text editor ought to have a function that tells us the numeric value of the character we've pointed at -- Emacs happily tells me that it's #x3042 -- so that would purely be a courtesy to those of us who probably shouldn't be messing with your code anyway.

Comment: If your question had been whether to use Japanese characters in your type and variable names -- which Java permits, I believe -- I might be more hesitant. That would tend to obscure the structure of the program for those of us who can't "read" these characters at least enough to remember a pattern from one place to another.

Comment: yes. Looks like variable names can have kanji! I should have tested and known that myself. I've got a lot of very good options now. I very much appreciate it.